# Incorporate HEv2 AAC into an MPEG-TS for HLS content

Tags: http-live-streaming, aac, mpeg2-ts

I try to find any info about AAC HEv2 (PS) in an MPEG Transport Stream (TS) for HLS.

According to the [HLS Authoring Specification for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/HLSAuthoringSpec/Requirements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016596-CH2-SW1) AAC HEv2 is a supported format. AAC HEv2 is part of MPEG-4, but I cannot understand how HEv2 could fit into a transport stream.

SBR (or HEv1) can be in TS by implicit signaling. In case of MP4 we have an audio specific config. But how can I multiplex AAC Parametric Stereo into the TS?

Is it available or not?
I cannot find any info from the Apple site and so on.

Comment: Every aac frame must have an adts header.

Comment: For implicit signaling ADTS header has audio object type = LC. To detect HEv1 I need to find extension elements (EXT SBR DATA or EXT SBR DATA CRC) in bitstream. But what should I do with HEv2? ADTS header cannot help me for implicit signaling.

Answer (score 2):

**There are two ways to put AAC into transport stream.**

1.
**Using ADTS syntax (MPEG2-style).**

In a such case PMT's stream_type should be specified as 0x0F (ISO/IEC 13818-7 Audio with ADTS transport syntax).

So, you are limited to using "old" (MPEG2) AAC versions only, without SBR and PS.

2.
**Using LATM+LOAS/AudioSyncStream syntax (MPEG4-style).**

In a such case PMT's stream_type should be specified as 0x11 (ISO/IEC 14496-3 Audio with the LATM transport syntax).

And you can use all the force of "new" (MPEG4) AAC features, including SBR and PS.

Furthermore, DVB standard ETSI TS 101 154 demands: HEv1/HEv2 AAC shall be transmitted using LATM syntax.